# Contact form 7 send to post author

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I would like to use the tag `[_post_author_email]` to send the contact form to post author.
On this post I have button "Send message" and after click it opens the form in popup. If the form is in popup the tag doesn't work - the author of the post was not recognized.
It it possible to fix it?

Comment: Can you please add the code?

Comment: @ShivendraSingh I add the `[_post_author_email]` in Recipient field in Contact Form 7 plugin. There's no additional code. I noticed that it doesn't work when the form is in popup window on the same page.